# Run Pylint for all Python files in a directory and all subdirectories

Tags: python, pylint

I have

```
find . -iname "*.py" -exec pylint -E {} ;\
```

and

```
FILES=$(find . -iname "*.py")
pylint -E $FILES
```

If I understand correctly, the first command will run pylint for each of the Python files, the second one will run pylint once for all files. I expected that both commands would return the same output, but they return different results. I think this diff is somehow related to imports and F (failure) pylint messages, which occurs when a import fails and is *not* output by pylint -E.

Has someone already experienced this and could explain why the diff happens and what is the best way to run pylint?

Answer (score 108):

Just pass the directory name to the pylint command. To lint all files in `./server`:

```
pylint ./server
```

Note that this requires the `__init__.py` file to exist in the target directory.

Comment: Not obvious at all. Should be able to do `pylint .` but that doesn't work. But this is *the* `pylint` answer without resorting to external binaries.

Comment: To be clear, if the directory does not contain `__init__.py` then you cannot run pylint from within a directory `server` that you wish to run it on. Both `pylint .` and `pylint ../server` fail. Instead, you must `cd ..; pylint server`. An alternative is to create a temporary `__init__.py` as in Ryan Feeley's answer.

Comment: @duhaime This works perfectly but the only problem i have is that is gives me overall score for all the files that it scans. Do you kniow how can I get the individual score for each file that pylint scans ?

Comment: @rahulrachh can you say more about what you mean by score? You mean pass / fail  score, or do you mean something more like codecoverage score?

Comment: @duhaime when we run pylint to check a python file. it gives us a score out of 10. I am talking about that score.

Comment: Hmm, you'd need to call pylint on each file individually in that case. Just create a loop and call pylint in the loop.

Comment: this is a great answer, thank you. Or: `pylint ${PWD}` if you want to pylint modules here and underneath (since `pylint .` is not a thing).

Comment: Technically, `pylint` does not take a directory name as the argument, it takes a package or module name. That's why the `__init__.py` is necessary, to make it a package instead of just a dir. https://docs.pylint.org/en/stable/user_guide/run.html

Comment: It should be noted when using this in a CI is that the exit-code for individual files is different to when you use a directory.

Comment: I just wonder, why its not listed in --help

Answer (score 78):

My one cent

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint
```

How does it work?

`find` finds all files ends with `py` and pass to `xargs`, `xargs` runs `pylint` command on each file.

NOTE: You can give any argument to `pylint` command as well.

EDIT:

According to [doc](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html) we can use

1. `pylint mymodule.py`
2. `pylint directory/mymodule.py`
3. `pylint ./module`

**number 2** will work if the directory is a python package (i.e. has an `__init__.py` file or it is an implicit namespace package) or if the “directory” is in the python path.

Comment: this is terrible. there is no pylint-centric solution?

Comment: Not portable if you don't have `find`. See other answers.

Comment: Not that this is my default solution, but if you have to use this solution then you should makes sure to explicitly tell it to ignore your vitural environment: `find . -type f -not -path "./venv/*" -name "*.py" | xargs pylint`

Comment: Any ides how to run the same on windows?

Comment: Tiny adjustment from @jimjim: if your virtual envs are hidden with a dot:
`find . -type f -not -path "./.venv/*" -name "*.py" | xargs pylint`

Comment: If you have node in your project as well, it can also contain python files. Here's the command that worked for me to exclude `.venv` and `node_modules`: `/usr/bin/find . -type f -name "*.py" -not -path "./.venv/*" -not -path "./node_modules/*" | xargs poetry run pylint`

Answer (score 71):

To run Pylint on all code in Git version control,

```
pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

This is *very* fast, as Git already knows the names of all of your files. It also works on macOS which lacks Bash 4, and also Windows. However it won't lint files that are very new and haven't been `git add`ed to the repos yet.

My thanks to national treasure Julia Evans for the `git ls-files` trick -- here's her original use case, automating workflows with "entr": https://jvns.ca/blog/2020/06/28/entr/

Comment: I like this answer because it also seems to work correctly on Windows under PowerShell, MacOS, Linux, etc...

Comment: No need for `git add`

Comment: in my observation the regular find command is faster than the git ls-files command.

Comment: to add also untracked files but ignoring the files in the standard Git exlusion (.gitignore) we can use following command `pylint $( git ls-files --exclude-standard --other -o '*.py';  git ls-files --exclude -o '*.py'; )`

Comment: Assumes a version control system managing the folder and that the system is `git`, though. Except for this, I like this answer.

Comment: I would give you a medal for this, not just an upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

To run pylint on all *.py files in a directory and its subdirectories, you can run:

```sh
shopt -s globstar  # for Bash
pylint ./**/*.py
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. Which version of pylint and which OS/Shell did you run this from?

Comment: Or use both in one line: `pylint *.py **/*.py` - runs for all py files in current dir and all subdirs

Comment: This does not run after installing pylint out of the box

Answer (score 9):

The pylint [docs](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html) makes mention of a `--recursive` flag, which tells pylint to find all modules and packages by itself without needing the user to manually specify all of them.

Therefore, all you need to do is:

```
pylint --recursive=y .
```

Looks like the flag was introduced in pylint [v2.13.0](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.13/full.html?highlight=--recursive#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-13-0). <s>but it seems that from v2.15.0 onwards, you won't need the `--recursive` flag, and that will be pylint's default behaviour.</s>

From 2.15.0, you [won't need the flag](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.15/index.html#summary-release-highlights) to detect namespace packages.

Comment: (2.15.10 with `--recursive=y`): Still only scans the `__init__.py` in my directory, not the `other.py` file next to it.

Comment: It must be accepted answer since 2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[UPDATED based on helpful additions in the comments]

If you don't have an `__init__.py` file in the directory, and you don't want to for various reasons, my approach is

```
touch __init__.py; pylint $(pwd); rm __init__.py
```

If you already have a `__init__.py` file in that directory, it will be **deleted**.

If you find yourself needing this functionality often, you should make a function that does this in a safer way that preserves a pre-existing `__init__.py` file. For example, you could put the following `pylint_all_the_things` function in your `~/.bashrc` file. (The last line exports the function so it can be called from any subshell.) If you don't want to edit `.bashrc`, you could put the function body in an executable shell script file.

This function defaults to running pylint in your current directory, but you can specify the directory to use as the 1st function argument.

```
# Run pylint in a given directory, defaulting to the working directory
pylint_all_the_things() {
    local d=${1:-$(pwd)}

    # Abort if called with a non-directory argument.
    if [ ! -d "${d}" ]; then
        echo "Not a directory: ${d}"
        echo "If ${d} is a module or package name, call pylint directly"
        exit 1
    fi

    local module_marker="${d}/__init__.py"

    # Cleanup function to later remove __init__.py if it doesn't currently exist
    [[ ! -f ${module_marker} ]] && local not_a_module=1
    cleanup() {
        (( ${not_a_module:-0} == 1 )) && rm "${module_marker}"
    }
    trap cleanup EXIT

    # Create __init__.py if it doesn't exist
    touch "${module_marker}"
    pylint "${d}"
    cleanup
}
export -f pylint_all_the_things
```

The `trap` utility is used to ensure the cleanup happens even if the call to `pylint` fails and you have `set -e` enabled, which causes the function to exit before reaching the cleanup line.

If you want to call `pylint` recursively on the current working directory and all subfolders, you could do something like

```
for dir in ./**/ ; do pylint_all_the_things "$dir"; done
```

Which will require globstar to be enabled in bash (`shopt -s globstar`).

Comment: `touch __init__.py; pylint \`pwd\`; rm __init__.py`

Comment: Better do `trap 'rm -f __init__.py' EXIT` to make sure it's removed even if pylint aborts.

Comment: An important clarification - `__init__.py` needs to be added in all subfolders with `.py` files.

Comment: remember not to delete `__init__.py` if you've had it in the first place.

Comment: I did `touch __init__.py; pylint .` but I get no output. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

I used in the root directory:

```
pylint *
```

Comment: --ignore <directory> 

if you should want to ignore let's say your virtualenv

Comment: Will crash if pylint tries to lint random non-Python files.

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer? It works exactly as expected and no external dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Im using the "pylint_runner" in order to run pylint on all files in the directory and the subdirectories.
Python 3.7.4

pylint_runner 0.54

pylint 2.4.1

https://pypi.org/project/pylint_runner/

Here is the command to run it from the Docker container:

```
docker run -i --rm --name my_container \
  -v "$PWD":"$PWD" -w "$PWD" \
    python:3.7 \
      /bin/sh -c "pip3 install -r requirements.txt; pylint_runner -v"
```

`requirements.txt` - should exist in the "$PWD" directory and contain "pylint_runner" entry.

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to run your custom configuration file use below command

```
pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc <directory_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is already an [issue for this](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/352) and hopefully gets fixed soon.

If you do not prefer to use `xargs` you can just do a plain find-exec:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec pylint -j 0 --exit-zero {} \;
```

The problem I had with `pylint Project-Dir` is that all the absolute imports were not working.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try prospector (https://pypi.org/project/prospector/) or pylint_runner ( https://pypi.org/project/pylint_runner/ )

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to run pylint on all files in the current working directory and subfolders, here is one workaround. This script runs pylint on the current directory. If `__init__.py` does not exist, it creates it, runs pylint, then removes it.

```
#! /bin/bash -
if [[ ! -e __init__.py ]]; then
    touch __init__.py
    pylint `pwd`
    rm __init__.py
else
    pylint `pwd`
fi
```

Comment: Better do `trap 'rm -f __init__.py' EXIT` to make sure it's removed even if pylint aborts. This would also allow to get rid of `else` branch.

Comment: An important clarification - `__init__.py` needs to be added in all subfolders with `.py` files. I ended up doing something like `files=; for d in $(find -name \*.py  | xargs dirname | sort -u); do if ! test -f $d/__init__.py; then touch $d/__init__.py; files="$files $PWD/$d/__init__.py"; fi; done; trap "rm -f $files" EXIT`

Comment: Good point -- you should submit your approach as a separate answer with a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To run Pylint in all subdirectories,

```
pylint $(find [a-z]* -type d)
```

This solution is simpler and more direct than others. It works with no setup, including on macOS which doesn't have Bash 4.

The reason for the `[a-z]*` is because most projects have Git or other magic subdirectories, which would pollute the results. If you have subdirectories starting with Capital Letters, use this variant:

```
pylint $(find [a-zA-Z]* -type d)
```

Answer (score 1):

using ./server or something similar only works if there is a `__init__.py` in all subdirs, it will not match all python files in all subdirs.
using find and xargs is an option, but this also works:

`pylint **py`

Answer (score 1):

Pylint v3.x seems to have a new --recursive flag

```bash
pylint --recursive=y .
```

> This option makes pylint attempt to discover all modules (files ending with .py extension) and all explicit packages (all directories containing a **init**.py file).

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html#on-module-packages-or-directories

Answer (score 0):

1. `touch __init__.py` in the current directory
2. `touch __init__.py` in every subdirectory that you want pylint to look at
3. `pylint $(pwd)` (or equivalently `pylint /absolute/path/to/current/directory`)

Answer (score 0):

What also works is the following command:

`pylint ./**/*.py`

or if you have your application code in a specific folder:

`pylint ./app/**/*.py`