# With Azure functions, how can we run a pylint task on the command line that checks each function?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, azure-functions, pylint, azure-function-app

We are building a Python 3.8 Azure functions project.  We have the following version of Pylint installed ...

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.6.0
astroid 2.4.2
Python 3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Our directory structure looks like the following ...

```
function1
    __init__.py
function2
    __init__.py
...
tests
    __init.py
```

Each function's **init**.py file is laid out in the traditional Azure functions way ...

```
import logging
...
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ...
```

However, I'm wondering how to run Pylint on the command line against all of our functions without having to specify each function.  I tried this

```
$ pylint .
************* Module .
__init__.py:1:0: F0010: error while code parsing: Unable to load file __init__.py:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '__init__.py' (parse-error)
```

It is our intention to eventually create a task in our Pipeline that will run Pylint against all of the functions.

Comment: Isn't it already answered in the following maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36873096

Answer (score 0):

On bash go up the folder and run your project folder.

Example `pylint project1` instead of `pylint .`

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue of pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/352

The problem is that you don't have `__init__.py` file at the root directory where from you execute `pylint` scan. That's why pylint doesn't start.

**The workaround** until issue gets fixed:

Add `__init__.py` at the root directory then pylint and after scan remove it if it's not necessary anymore.

**Solution**:
You are in root dir `"./"` where from all `./function1`, `./function2`, `./tests` are available.

```
touch __init__.py;
pylint $(pwd)
rm __init__.py
```

It works everywhere: in azure-pipelines.yaml and in gitlab-ci.yml and locally.

I checked it at my [template](https://github.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/azure-pipeline-pylint-template/blob/473b9d4b636ee6d85108a3465381b0e3862e1922/azure-pipelines.yml) project:

```
- script: |
    touch __init__.py
    pylint .
    rm __init__.py
  displayName: 'pylint .'

- script: |
    touch __init__.py
    pylint $(pwd)
    rm __init__.py
  displayName: 'pylint $pwd'
```

`pylint .`:
https://dev.azure.com/Jet-Cat/azure-pipeline-pylint-template/_build/results?buildId=61&view=logs&j=00b6a206-eb91-585b-3d14-cf1a4d7b1970&t=9a9400f1-b707-5d54-e2fd-4fe1d8bc6dda

`pylint $(pwd)`:
http://dev.azure.com/Jet-Cat/azure-pipeline-pylint-template/_build/results?buildId=61&view=logs&j=00b6a206-eb91-585b-3d14-cf1a4d7b1970&t=b5464ffe-109e-5907-849b-650dd16a8b4d