# How to Run Pylint to check score of entire folder in a project

Tags: python, pycharm, pylint

when i try to run this command in windows to check my entire folder score which contains .py files

`pylint C:\path-to- folder\\*.py`

am getting error as follows

`F0001: No module named C:/path/*.py (fatal)`

please help me to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Pylint for all Python files in a directory and all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873096/run-pylint-for-all-python-files-in-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories)

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question: [Run Pylint for all Python files in a directory and all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873096/run-pylint-for-all-python-files-in-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories)

From the answers there, for your question:

If your directory structure was

```
C
|—->abc
    —> def
|—>projects
    —>code
      —> __init__.py
      —> other_file.py
      —> main.py
```

```
cd C:\projects\
pylint code
```

For some reason you need to go up one level and then run pylint on the folder from above. Also make sure your folder has an `__init__.py`.

You could also try

```
cd C:\projects\code
pylint .
```

Comment: your solution is not workig i didnn't understand

Comment: What didn’t you understand?

Comment: Why its not working if i give pylint  c:\some-path\*.py if i give individual file am getting score

Comment: i am in pylint folder only after that i am giving pylint c:\path\*.py   am getting same error

Comment: Ah. pylint wants either a single file or a single directory as an argument, not a regex

Comment: I want whole files of .py extensions in a folder how to do that am passing *.py how to pass other way?

Comment: If i give directory as argument its not working am getting F0010: error while code parsing: Unable to load file

Comment: Does my update answer your question? Please also read the linked question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73227403/4687939), starting in version 2.13.0 you can run

```
pylint --recursive=y .
```